# Compute $(\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(2,4)\rangle$ using the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

I'm trying to get the hang of factor group computations so I made up a problem for myself to try to solve. For practice, I tried computing $(\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(2,4)\rangle$ using the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups. Here's my solution:

First, we see that $\langle(2,4)\rangle=\{(2,4),(0,0)\}$, so $|\langle(2,4)\rangle|=2.$ Therefore, we have that

$$|(\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(2,4)\rangle|=\frac{|\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_8|}{|\langle(2,4)\rangle|}=\frac{32}{2}=16, $$

so according to the Fundamental Theorem, our factor group $(\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(2,4)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{16},\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8,$ or $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$. Consider the coset $(0,1)+\langle(2,4)\rangle$. This coset has order 8 since $8(0,1)=(0,0).$ Since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_8,$ $(0,1)+\langle(2,4)\rangle$ is the element with the largest possible order in $(\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(2,4)\rangle$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8$ is the only group out of the possibilites presented whose elements have a maximum order of $8$, we conclude $(\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(2,4)\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8.$

Did I get the right answer, and is my thought process correct here?

Comment: You have successfully shown that the group is not $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_4$, but you haven't eliminated the possibility of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$. For example, the element $2$ has order 8 in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$. However, you are very close. If you show in addition that there are two elements of order 2, you will be done, since $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ is cyclic and can only have one element of order 2

Comment: @peabody Ah, so I couldn't conclude $(0,1)+\langle(2,4)\rangle$ has the largest possible order since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_8$?

Comment: And two elements of order $2$ are $(1,2)+\langle(2,4)\rangle$ and $(0,4)+\langle(2,4)\rangle$, correct?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean here. In this case, you can conclude that, but, if you were working with more abstract groups, you would need to make some notes about the groups in the product. Namely, you are taking the quotient of the product of cyclic groups, with the order of one of the groups dividing the other. So, the maximal order of a single element in the resulting group can be at most the maximal order in one of the terms in the product. If we were to work with something like $\mathbb{Z}_{6}\times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, then we might not get as nice of behavior.

Comment: And yes, those two elements work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof can be made more direct. It is easy to check that for each $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}/4×\mathbb{Z}/8$ the equation $8(a,b)=(8a,8b)=e$ holds. This implies that every element has order $8<16$ even in $\mathbb{Z}/4×\mathbb{Z}/8$. So conclude that every elenent in your quotient group has order at most $8<16$ and thus as the quotient group has $16$ elements, it cannot be cyclic.

Comment: So usually finding the kernel like you did can streamline the process?